# How to add a macro to ThisWorkbook Workbook_Open with C# Excel Interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I developed a Windows Service using C# that processes a number of Excel files in a folder to add conditional formatting, adjust page layout and print settings and add a macro to adjust page breaks. The problem I'm having is trying to add a line of code to the ThisWorkbook object in the Workbook_Open routine to automatically run the macro when the file is opened. The code I'm using to add the macro to Module1 is as follows:

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
    using VBIDE = Microsoft.Vbe.Interop;

    VBIDE.VBComponent oModule;
    String sCode;

    oModule = wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);

    sCode = 
@"Sub FixPageBreaks()
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = wb.Worksheets(1)

    Dim vBreaks As VPageBreaks
    Set vBreaks = sheet.VPageBreaks

    If vBreaks.Count > 0 Then
        Dim lastCol As Integer
        lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=""*"", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column

        Dim lCount As Integer
        lCount = 1

        Dim brkCol As Integer

        Dim brkRng As Range

        Dim iReply As VbMsgBoxResult

        Do
            If vBreaks(lCount).Location.Column = lastCol Then
                brkCol = vBreaks(lCount).Location.Column + 1
            Else
                brkCol = vBreaks(lCount).Location.Column - 1
            End If

            Set brkRng = Range(sheet.Cells(1, brkCol), sheet.Cells(1, brkCol))

            If brkCol Mod 2 = 1 And lastCol > brkCol Then
                Set vBreaks(lCount).Location = brkRng
            ElseIf brkCol Mod 2 = 1 Then
                vBreaks(lCount).DragOff Direction:=xlToRight, RegionIndex:=1
            End If

            lCount = lCount + 1
        Loop While lCount <= vBreaks.Count

        sheet.PrintPreview
    End If
Exit Sub
ErrMsg:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub";

    oModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

In the line

```
wb.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(VBIDE.vbext_ComponentType.vbext_ct_StdModule);
```

**wb** is the workbook object instantiated earlier in the code. This all works, however, I can't seem to find much documentation on the vbext_ComponentType enumeration to determine which one (if any) represent the ThisWorkbook object in the workbook and how to add code to it. I would also be happy with finding C# code that does the same thing to page breaks as the macro in the Excel document. The only reason I'm not doing it in C# like the rest of the processing is that I was unable to make it work. Any help there would be equally helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var workbookMainModule = wkBk.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("ThisWorkbook");
                workbookMainModule.CodeModule.AddFromString(sCode);
```

Comment: Some explanation could have been helpful here